# Codeception, use methods _after _before.. in an AcceptanceTester class

Tags: php, codeception

I create a gherkin scenario and implement mandatory method in the `AcceptanceTester` class in `tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php` file.

From this file, I want to use `_after` method to execute some stuff after my tests are executed.

If I am in a `Cest` File, I can use `_after` method, but from the `AcceptanceTester` file this method is never called.

Why? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcceptanceTester` does not support the `_after` method. If you look deeper into its parent class/traits, you'll see that no such method exists.

However, if you want to run your custom code before/after the test suite runs, then you can create your custom `Helper` class with `_beforeSuite` and/or `_afterSuite` methods, respectively. Have a look at answers posted to this question:

[Run custom code after Codeception suite has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242629/run-custom-code-after-codeception-suite-has-finished)